# File name printed twice when using wc

Tags: linux, shell, wc

For printing number of lines in all ".txt" files of current folder, I am using following script:

```
for f in *.txt;
do l="$(wc -l "$f")";
echo "$f" has "$l" lines;
done
```

But in output I am getting:

```
lol.txt has 2 lol.txt lines
```

Why is `lol.txt` printed twice (especially after 2)? I guess there is some sort of stream flush required, but I dont know how to achieve that in this case.So what changes should i make in the script to get the output as :

```
lol.txt has 2 lines
```

Comment: If you just run `wc -lol.txt` from the command line it should then be obvious what's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the filename with 'cut':

```
for f in *.txt;
do l="$(wc -l "$f" | cut -f1 -d' ')";
echo "$f" has "$l" lines;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The filename is printed twice, because `wc -l "$f"` also prints the filename after the number of lines. Try changing it to `cat "$f" | wc -l`.

Comment: Or read the number using `read`: `wc -l /etc/passwd | { read n rest ; echo $n ; }`

Comment: no but a little bit more reliable. It could be possible that there is a wc which prints /dev/stdin instead of nothing while reading from stdin.

Comment: I have yet to encounter such a `wc`, but I suppose it is possible.

Comment: From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html: `If no input file operands are specified, no name shall be written and no <blank> characters preceding the pathname shall be written.`

Answer (score 1):

`wc` prints the filename, so you could just write the script as:

```
ls *.txt | while read f; do wc -l "$f"; done
```

or, if you really want the verbose output, try

```
ls *.txt | while read f; do wc -l "$f" | awk '{print $2, "has", $1, "lines"}'; done
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick here. Get wc to read stdin and it won't print a file name:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    l=$(wc -l < "$f")
    echo "$f" has "$l" lines
done
```

Comment: what is the exact diff between (1) l=$(wc -l < "$f") and (2) l="$(wc -l "$f")"; ???

Comment: With the redirected for, wc doesn't get a file name and wc treats this case specially and only outputs the count(s)